# How to Bold or Color a JTable Row Which Contain Specfic Text at Runtime in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a a `JTable` which retrieve and show data from Database

The show data is as follow in JTable
[image]

in the above image in 2nd column there are plenty `TOTAL` and in 1st column `Grand Total`. My Question is i want to make the Column which contain `TOTAL` and `Grand Total` columns entire row must be Bold or any brackground color to make it more specfic.

Please Help

Comment: You need a `TableCellRenderer` which is capable of doing so. The means by which you would ultimately implement it would come down to the structure of the data, as each cell would need to be able to determine if it should be bold or not based on the status of the first two columns

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Comment: to cast the String value from column (view can returns an Object) and by using prepareRenderer

Answer (score 1):

Currently it looks like your table stores all the data as String data so the suggestion to create a custom renderer would work.

However, I don't it makes sense to use Strings for all the data. I see many columns with numbers, both Integer and Double values. In these columns the data should be stored as Integer and Double, so an appropriate renderer can be used to display the data.

In this case you would now need to create multiple renderers to highlight the rows of data.

For an alternative approach you can customize the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of the table to do the row highlighting. This method doesn't care about the data so the logic is only required in one place.

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for working examples of this approach.